# Spring annotation transaction rollback done not working for two tables

Tags: java, spring

I'm facing one problem, if there are two insert statement and there is exception in second insert query, rollback is not working properly.

Insert 1 for table `PatientDemographics` SUCCESS
Insert 2 for table `EncounterHistory` FAILS

Then result of insert 1 should not rollback (not revert from database automatically, it is to insert a record in the database).

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void addPatientDemographicsAndEncounterHistory(PatientDemographicsDTO patientDemographicsDTO, int count) throws  Exception{
// save patient demographics data
PatientDemographics patientDemographics = new PatientDemographics();
patientDemographics.setFullName(patientDemographicsDTO.getFullName());
patientDemographics.setMedicalRecordNumber(patientDemographicsDTO.getMedicalRecordNumber());
mednetDAO.saveOrUpdate(patientDemographics);

if(count == 1){
    throw new Exception(count+" Records Saved");
}
// save patient encounter history
EncounterHistory encounterHistory = new EncounterHistory();
encounterHistory.setCompanyID(patientDemographics.getDefaultCompanyID());
encounterHistory.setPatientID(patientDemographics.getPersonID());
encounterHistory.setDepartmentID(patientDemographics.getLastDepartmentID());
encounterHistory.setDoctorID(patientDemographics.getLastDoctorID());
encounterHistory.setLastOPDDate(patientDemographics.getLastOPDDate());

encounterHistory.setLastOPDFreeCount(patientDemographics.getLastOPDFreeCount());
encounterHistory.setLastNotesID(null);
encounterHistory.setLastIPDDate(null);
encounterHistory.setLastIPDFreeCount(patientDemographics.getLastIPDFreeCount());
mednetDAO.saveOrUpdate(encounterHistory);
 }
```

Comment: Just remove the `@Transactional` if you don't want rollback to occur

Answer (score 0):

In its default configuration, the Spring Framework’s transaction infrastructure code only marks a transaction for rollback in the case of runtime, unchecked exceptions; that is, when the thrown exception is an instance or subclass of `RuntimeException`. Checked exceptions that are thrown from a transactional method do not result in rollback in the default
configuration.

Remove `throws` from your method signature and throw `RuntimeException` :

```
if(count == 1){
   throw new RuntimeException(count+" Records Saved");
}
```